# adding multiple arrays with a limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have three sources of data that return arrays ranging in amount. I want to create one array of results from these while limiting the amount I can get back.

```
var array1 = ["one"];
var array2 = ["two", "three", "four"];
var array3 = ["five", "six", "seven"];
```

I want to only bring back the first 6 results, but they can come from any one of the three arrays in order. From the above example I would expect to see `"one, two, three, four, five, six"` returned.

I achieved this using multiple for loops, with multiple if statements:

```
var tList = [];
var tCount = 0;
var tLimit = 5;

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (tCount <= tLimit) {
        tList.push(array1[i]);
        tCount++;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (tCount <= tLimit) {
        tList.push(array2[i]);
        tCount++;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
    if (tCount <= tLimit) {
        tList.push(array3[i]);
        tCount++;
    }
}
```

however this doesn't seem like the best or tidiest approach to this, Is there a better way of achieving the same goal? without using a plugin like underscore.

here's a jsfiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/sju7g5dp/

Comment: Concatenate all the arrays, then slice off the first n elements. `[].concat(array1, array2, array3).slice(0, 5)`.

Comment: @torazaburo is this still best practice if say the first array had 6 results already, to still go ahead and do the rest and then remove them

Comment: Unless, you expect there to be a total of 10,000 elements, and you only want to take the first five, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concat()` method is used to join two or more `arrays`.

This method does not change the existing `arrays`, but returns a new `array`, containing the values of the joined `arrays`.

```
var array1 = ["one"];
var array2 = ["two", "three", "four"];
var array3 = ["five", "six", "seven"];
var result=array1.concat(array2,array3);
console.log(result);
```

then simply slice it ,

`result.slice(0,5)`

Comment: What about *while limiting the amount I can get back*?

Comment: so you would recommend adding all the data together, then just removing those after my limit? so say `result.slice(0,5)`?

Comment: @torazaburo just updated the code, yes you can just slice it, I missed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function take(limit) {
  var result = []
  for (var i = 0, args = arguments.length - 1; result.length < limit && i < args; i++)
    for (var j = 0, length = arguments[i].length; result.length < limit && j < length; j++)
      result.push(arguments[i][j])
  return result
}

console.log(take(5, [1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]))
  /* output: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] */
```

May not be pleasing to the eye with the for loops, but it does what you want.  Takes up to N elements from an arbitrary number of array sources.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using ES6 generators.

First, write a generator which generates elements from an array of arrays.

```
function *elts(arrays) { 
  for (let array of arrays) yield *array; 
}
```

Next, the `take` generator yields the first *n* results from an iterator.

```
function *take(n, it) { 
  for (let x of it) if (n--) yield x; else break; 
}
```

Now,

```
var array1 = ["one"];
var array2 = ["two", "three", "four"];
var array3 = ["five", "six", "seven"];

var arrays = [array1, array2, array3];

console.log(Array.from(take(6, elts(arrays))));

> ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
```